# How do i decide the value of \$R\$,\$L\$ and \$K\$ in the bandgap when i want a specific \$V_{ref}\$

Tags: voltage, mosfet, bjt

The bandgap schematic is as below,i read books about it,and find that books only teach us how to decide the value of \$R\$,\$L\$,and \$K\$,but doesn't teach us that if we want specific value of \$V_{ref}\$,how do we decide the value of \$R\$,\$L\$ and \$K\$.

So i want ask if i want a \$V_{ref}\$ for 1.98v,how do i decide the value of R,L and K,
according to the formula

\$V_{ref}\$=\$V_{D3}\$+\$L\times n\times lnK\times V_T\$,it seems that we can derived them from this formula ,but the \$V_{D3}\$ has a relation with L and R,so i don't know how to decide the value of  \$R\$,\$L\$ and \$K\$ from this formula

[image]

Comment: Not a single question mark. What is your question?

Comment: How do i decide the value if L,R and K,when i want a specific Vref,for example,Vref=1.98V

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the simulation of it is about 1.3v,then it is fixed,it can't provide voltage which is larger than 1.3v,but it may provide voltage less than 1.3V,if you still want a larger voltage,your error will goes up.So the only way is to find another circuit that can provide larger voltage.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I1 = I2, then a K of 8 (meaning the emitter area of D2 is 8X the area of D1) provides log2(8)=3 * 18 milliVolts = 54 milliVolts across R.

You can scale up L*R to get close to what you want; the D3 provides some needed temperature compensation.